# How to extract and load all .mat files from subfolders with different names

Tags: matlab, directory

My aim is to load all `.mat` files from a single directory.

Let's say my file of interest is called data.mat, within a directory `('C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Experiment1)`.

The problem is that the subfolder "Experiment1" contains further subfolders (for example, `('C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Experiment1\Subject1\January1\data.mat)`, and I want Matlab to bypass the subfolders and extract all 'data.mat files' from Experiment1.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do this?

Here is my current script:

```
mainFolder = dir('C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Experiment1');
for i = 1:numel(mainFolder)
    eval(['data_',num2str(i)]) = load('data.mat');
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, they all have the same names ('data.mat'). I will rename the structures as I load them.

Comment: Sorry about that, thank you.

Comment: Are there any subclass directories in there, prefixed with '+' or '@' for example?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. How would I find this?

Comment: You would see this in your File Explorer (windows explorer?).  I wasn't sure if your subpaths were mixed in with MATLAB code or classes, but it sounds like that is not the case.  Give me a few minutes, I'll put an answer together for you to try.

Comment: You are correct, the subpaths are not mixed with other code/classes. Thanks so much, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`dir`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html), which searches recursively if you include the `**` wildcard.

For example:

```
datafiles = dir(fullfile(pathname, '**', 'data.mat'))
for ii = 1:length(datafiles)
    tmp = load(fullfile(datafiles(ii).folder, datafiles(ii).name));

    datastr = sprintf('data_%u', ii);  % Generate data string
    data.(datastr) = tmp
end
```

Comment: Hmm, this does not show up in my test cases (MATLAB R2014).  That is, datafiles is empty when I try running it, even when pathname is in the same directory with a 'data.mat' file.  Is there is a unix/windows difference?  This would be a better solution.

Comment: Then this is much nicer! (+1)

Comment: Archaic matlab users (aka. before R2016b), you can use this function, subdir, to replace dir in @excaza's code above. Here's the link:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15859-subdir--a-recursive-file-search

Thanks again for your help!!